# Spring Security: autowire ProviderManager

Tags: google-app-engine, spring-security, spring

I am trying to programatically validate a user login/pass using Spring Security, so I need to have access to the `ProviderManager`.  I would like it to be automatically injected into my `@Controller`.

My code looks like:

```
import org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager;

// ...

@Controller
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    private ProviderManager authenticationManager;
```

But when I try to run the application I get this error message:

```
No unique bean of type [org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager] is defined: 
expected single matching bean but found 2: 
[org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0, org.springframework.security.authenticationManager]
```

What could be the cause or how could I solve it?

I am using Spring Security 3.0.0-RC1 with Spring 3.0.1, and I've not defined any `ProviderManager` bean. I've successfully used:

```
@Resource
private ProviderManager authenticationManager;
```

in other projects, but `javax.annotation.Resource` is not supported in GAE.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two `AuthenticationManager`s in the context:

- `org.springframework.security.authenticationManager` is populated with authentication providers explicitly declared in `<authentication-manager>`
- `org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0` is populated with implicitly declared providers (remember me, anonymous and so on) and delegates the authentication request to `org.springframework.security.authenticationManager` as a fallback.

So, I guess you need

```
@Autowired @Qualifier("org.springframework.security.authenticationManager")
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know @Qualifier annotation.  Do you know if it is related someway with the "alias" attribute (<sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">) that seems to solve the problem as well ?

Comment: @Guido: Yes, your solution works almost the same way. `@Qualifier` uses the specified name to choose one of the beans, when your solution chooses that bean because its alias matches the field name.

Answer (score 4):

The error message goes away including an alias for the authentication-manager:

```
<sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
```

and upgrading to Spring Security 3.0.0 finale.