# How to reload Spring Security Principal after updating in Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, spring-security, hibernate-generic-dao

This must be a common issue... and I feel that after googling, and SOing I must have just not looked around thoroughly for the answer enough or that no1 has asked it... so please forgive me.

I am using Spring Security with Hibernate etc.

So a User/principal has logged in and made some changes to their profile.

I use my DAO to update the profile (UserDetails), and I want my Principal to automatically reflect this update.

However when I get the Principal again, I get the dirty version (from my initial login).

Does anyone know of how I can get Spring Security to reload from Hibernate the updated UserDetails?

Comment: OK I found something that helped me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398224/spring-security-autowire-providermanager

Getting the Provider Manager allowed me to reauthenticate.

Now the problem seems to be that the new Principal has all the periphery references lazy initialized causing it to throw exceptions further down the line

Comment: That's really more of a Hibernate / ORM strategy problem, and not so much a Spring Security problem, though... right?

Comment: Yeah I looked into it a bit more and it seems that Spring Sec makes the UserDetails immunitable for security reasons. As such, the best practice is to re-login the userdetails by forcing them to reenter their password.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

OK dug around and finally found the answer.

We can create a UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken and assign the updated Principal to the context.

```
Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userObject, userObject.getPassword(), userObject.getAuthorities());
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
```

See also "[How to manually set an authenticated user in Spring Security / SpringMVC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4672083/244439)".

Comment: Your solution works. I would, however, use a `PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken` instead of a `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`. This basically does the same thing - it just helps to clarify your intent and enhances readability of your code

Comment: This is updating the authorities in authentication object but not in principal. any idea how to update principal?

Comment: My `userObject.getPassword()` is null (for security reasons we're unable to get the password), any way it can be done without the password?

Comment: @TomBom You're allowed to pass `null` as the password.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem

i fixed it with getting the authentication from SecurityContextHolder cast it's principal to User then update principal.

everything is working but i don't know this is a good practice or not.