# How to updated principal after updating user in database?

Tags: grails, spring-security, spring-ldap

I think I'm asking the same thing that the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7889660/how-to-reload-spring-security-principal-after-updating-in-hibernate) is asking.

Here is what I am doing:

1.) A user that is not in my database logs in to my application for the first time.

2.) The user is authenticated via LDAP

3.) I listen for an `AuthenticationSuccessEvent`.  When detected I add the user to the my database if they do not exist, or update their info with the LDAP info if they do exist.

My problem is that if I add a user to my database for the first time they don't have an `id` until after they are added.  I want to update the `principal` so `id` is accessible from the `principal` object.

I have tried the approach described [here](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?87771-Reload-Update-custom-UserDetails-without-logging-out) but it didn't work.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, and it may even be impossible without code examples.

Comment: What I am saying is the principal's `id` is not accessible until they exist in my database (obviously), but even after the principal is added to the database there does not seem to be a good way to update the principal object during their current session.  Thus, the principal's `id` cannot be accessed from the principal object until they are added to the database, log out, then log back in.

Comment: If you're using a sequence, after `principal.save()`, you should have an id in principal.  If not, you need to flush the session.