# Update Principal in Session when using Spring-Session

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-session

We have extended the principal with our own User object. This way the object is available with every request.
When a user updates his information, the principal needs to updated with this new data. When not using spring-session, [this method works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7889660/how-to-reload-spring-security-principal-after-updating-in-hibernate). However, with spring-session, it does not.

I checked in the spring-session code, and the `RedisOperationsSessionRepository:save(RedisSession session)` only calls `session.saveDelta()`, which only saves changed attributes. So, how do we update a principal in session?

Note - the place where the principal is updated is in the service layer, so we do not have access to a `SessionAuthenticationStrategy`.

Answer (score 8):

Found a way to do this, so answering my own question. Spring-security stores the context as an attribute in `HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY`. So updating the key manually (instead of through Spring-Session) results in the Principal being updated.

```
httpSession.setAttribute(
  HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY,
  SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is enough to set a new `Authentication` object. You can recreate it reusing some parts from old:

```java
final Authentication oldAuth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
final Authentication newAuth = new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken(
        newDetails, oldAuth.getCredentials(), oldAuth.getAuthorities());
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(newAuth);
```

If the reference for `Authentication` has changed this triggers updates to session storage (be it Redis or whatever)...

Setting **special magical session attribute** `HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY` (the constant `"SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT"` is spread across Spring Security classes) also might trigger propagation of a new value through session storage (like Redis or DB), for example in `RedisSessionRepository` `attributeName` is placed to `delta` for saving:

```
@Override
public void setAttribute(String attributeName, Object attributeValue) {
    this.cached.setAttribute(attributeName, attributeValue);
    this.delta.put(getAttributeKey(attributeName), attributeValue);
    flushIfRequired();
}
```