# Reload/Change UserDetails in Spring for Extra Information

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have started switching my application over to use Spring Security.  I have a custom `UserDetailsServiceImpl` which is returning my custom `UserDetails` which contain the standard Spring stuff (roles, etc.), as well as some application specific references, IE: `currentWorkspace`.

I am tracking the `currentWorkspace` in the DB and it is loaded properly in the initial `loadUserByUsername`.  In my Spring MVC when I change something in my `UserDetails` like `currentWorkspace`, how can I trigger a reload of the `UserDetails`, or modify the current `Principal` and push it into the session in place of the outdated one?

Is it as simple as just calling `loadUserByUsername` in my `UserDetailsService` and Spring will handle the rest?  Do I have to mess around with the `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` and set something there?  I figured this was something simple but can't figure out what to do.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7889660/how-to-reload-spring-security-principal-after-updating-in-hibernate

Comment: Are you fine with reloading `UserDetails` on every HTTP request? If yes, please take a look at my solution posted in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26393518/spring-security-logoff-a-user-while-runtime/26697333#26697333